# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: object is undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```js
<script>
        const app = new Vue({
            el: '#app', 
            data:{
                results:{}
            },
            mounted()
            {
                axios.get('{{ route('request.data') }}').then(response=>this.results = response.data)
            }
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<span class="company-value" v-text="results.request_stats.new"></span>
```

As in title this is the error I am getting. but When I `console.log(object)` the value is there and it is not null. So what is the point of this error

Note: object=results.request_stats

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: added the code. i am calling an ajax request on the route and it is returning back an object results

Comment: Please add the relevant code. There is no `object`, no `console.log`, and no `results.request_stats` in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare and assign some value like `{}` or `[]` to bind , otherwise you will get Undefined error for `request_stats.new`

```js
const app = new Vue({
            el: '#app', 
            data:{
                results:{request_stats:{}},
                loading:true
            },
            mounted()
            {
              var vm = this;
               setTimeout(function(){ 
                vm.loading = false;
                vm.results.request_stats.new = "Niklesh Raut";
               }, 1000);
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div>
<span class="company-value" v-text="results.request_stats.new"></span>
<div v-show="loading">loading...</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Without assigning, which is giving error

```js
const app = new Vue({
            el: '#app', 
            data:{
                results:{},
                loading:true
            },
            mounted()
            {
              var vm = this;
               setTimeout(function(){ 
                vm.loading = false;
                vm.results.request_stats.new = "Niklesh Raut";
               }, 1000);
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div>
<span class="company-value" v-text="results.request_stats.new"></span>
<div v-show="loading">loading...</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to initialize every object and array which can be dynamic when I get them from the server??

Comment: @AhmedNawazKhan: Yes boss to bind object.

Comment: You can also read about [how data binds](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods)

Comment: well this is insane. the data may be dynamic. you may never know what is comming arrays objects etc

Comment: Can you share any situation where you dont know about data type ? Array have object and object have array.

Comment: @AhmedNawazKhan how did you figure it out?

Comment: assign some initial values

Answer (score 1):

a work around is to add to your span the following snippet

```
v-if="results && results.request_stats"
```